# How can i solve specified module could not be found Error in Asp.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and create ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application.
Here i add SQL Server database after that i want to create new table that time "The Specified module could not found" error was come. I don't know how to solve that.

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be due to an update, someone has wrote this:

> The problem seems to be with the Visual Database Tools DLL.
>
> This DLL file is installed by the VS 2010 installation, but during a
>   SQL Server 2012 installation, it will be upgraded to the SQL 2012
>   version of the tools. Thereafter, uninstalling and reinstalling SQL or
>   VS will not remove this newer DLL in order to allow the older version
>   to be installed, and hence leave this annoying issue.
>   How I fixed it was I set up a clean virtual machine and installed VS
>   2010, then took this original DLL from my virtual machine and
>   overwrote the DLL on my live machine. Simple as that.
>
> I would assume though that deleting this DLL file and then doing a VS
>   2010 repair or uninstall/reinstall would also fix the problem.
>
> The directory and file name of the DLL (on an X64 machine) is:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Visual Database
>   Tools\dsref80.dll

See the entire [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d65c71f5-3887-4f2a-bbd3-e799a4ac6fdc/visual-studio-database-tools-error?forum=vstsdb) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below  url this will help you:
You have to uninstall visual studio and then you have to install it.
http://seesharpaspdotnet.blogspot.in/2013/02/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found.html

Answer (score 1):

I found this at

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6793785a-ec98-4453-a62b-f1a85195ec05/unable-to-load-dll-hresult-0x8007007e?forum=csharpgeneral

" Try to copy the SQLBOOT.DLL from your SQL serverInstallation kit and Paste to the

following location "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn"

Seems the SQLBOOT.DLL is missed or corrupted do the aboce steps as I mentioned and try to start it. "

Hope it helps